# TailwindCSS: Access parent element's background in linear-gradient

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to do something but I'm not sure if it's possible. Let's say I have a button inside a div with a background.

```xml
<div class="bg-trueGray-300 dark:bg-blueGray-700">
    <button class="btn-img-1 h-24 w-48">TEXT</button>
</div>
```

I want this image to "fade in the background" so to speak. To that end, I've done this:

```css
.btn-img-1 {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(to right, theme('colors.blueGray.700'), transparent),
        url('../../public/img/buttons/my-img.png');
}
```

It works...  when the dark mode is toggled on. I'd like it to be dynamic. Instead of specifying `theme('colors.blueGray.700')`, I'd like something like `inherit`.

Is it possible?

My current "workaround" so to speak is just to specify the rule multiple times.

```css
.btn-img-1 {
    ...
}

html.dark .btn-img-1 {
    ...
}
```

But my concern is that this is completely dependent on me using those background colors to begin with and the fact this will bloat up my stylesheet considerably if I add behavior for `:hover` and `:focus` states.